# When using a web component in Svelte, how to solve the issue that the component emits events before listeners are attached to it?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, svelte, sveltekit

I am using a web component in a svelte project.

Below is how it is used in a svelte component:

```
    <formkit-component
        on:pageTitleUpdated={(event) => updatePageTitle(event.detail)}
        schema={schema}
    />
```

The web component has a setter for field `schema`:

```
set schema(schema) {
        this._schema = schema;

        this.dispatchEvent(
            new CustomEvent('pageTitleUpdated', {
                detail: this.pageTitle
            })
        );
    }
```

so when `schema` is set, a `pageTitleUpdated` event is emitted, and the parent Svelte component is supposed to receive it and do something in the `updatePageTitle()` function.

The problem is that the event is always emitted BEFORE the listener for the `pageTitleUpdated` event is attached in the parent Svelte component, therefore the event is lost.

If I added a timeout for the event emission, like

```
set schema(schema) {
    this._schema = schema;
    
    // This "setTimeout" is newly added.
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new CustomEvent('pageTitleUpdated', {
                detail: this.pageTitle
            })
        );
    }, 1000)
}
```

then the event can be caught with no problem. But adding a timeout seems to be a hacky solution.

I wonder if there is a way to make sure the event is not emitted from the child web component UNTIL the parent Svelte component has created the listener.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only way is too add listeners yourself using `addEventListener()` instead of using the svelte way `on:eventName`.

This way, you have the info about when all the listeners have been attached, then you can set a flag, like `areAllListenersAttached: boolean`, to true, and pass this flag to the web component.

In the web component, you need to check if this flat is `true` before emitting events. If it is still `false`, the event dispatcher needs to wait until it becomes `true`. To make it wait, I used `setTimeout()`, which checks the flag every 100ms.